# OpenCV Audio support (MSMF and GStreamer backends)

Tags: opencv

As it's mentioned in [Release highlights](https://opencv.org/opencv-4-5-5/), OpenCV (4.5.5) now have Audio support in videoio module. However, there's no documentation related on this topic.

I've tried a few things on my own like:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(fileName,cv::CAP_MSMF);
```

However, no results so far.

How can I activate Audio Support? Am I missing something?
(Does not work neither for camera nor video files)

Additionally, I don't use pre-built binaries but, tried with pre-built ones(for Windows) and it didn't work neither.

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems the functionality is implemented in those respective backends, but there's no existing interface exposing it yet. So for all practical purposes, there's no audio support yet for an end-user of OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek. It seems I have to do some modifications to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, this question does not make any sense unless they implement an interface. That's why they have no documentation about this topic. Hope they'll bring that feature with 4.5.6.